# Delete rows by pair of columns that exist in a table

Tags: sql, sqlite, delete-row, sql-delete

I have a table and I need to delete rows by two columns, for example

```
+------+------+--------+
| col1 | col2 |  other |
+------+------+--------+
|  12  |   2  |  test  |
+------+------+--------+
|  14  |   2  |  test1 |
+------+------+--------+
|  12  |   3  |  test2 |
+------+------+--------+
|  13  |   3  |  test3 |
+------+------+--------+
|  15  |   4  |  test4 |
+------+------+--------+
```

and I want to delete rows that have (col1,col2) pair equal any values in (12,2),(13,3),(14,2)

Can I do this by pure SQL?

Comment: which database-manager you are using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a lot of values, populate a table with them and do:

```
DELETE t
FROM Table t
INNER JOIN TempTable tt
ON t.col1 = tt.col1
AND t.col2 = tt.col2
```

Comment: Note that this solution does not work with sqlite.   See this SO solution for sqlite: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511153/how-delete-table-inner-join-with-other-table-in-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

Try the following sql:

```
delete from <tablename> 
where (col1 = 12 and col2 = 2) 
   or (col1 = 13 and col2 = 3) 
   or (col1 = 14 and col2 = 2)
```

Comment: Hi, I have lots of pair that must be deleted and I hoped to be able to use something like "IN" statement. no other solution?

Comment: See e.g. solution provided by JNK.