# How delete table inner join with other table in Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

My query:

```
DELETE a FROM TR_ContactResultRecord  a
INNER JOIN TR_Case  b on (a.FireStationCode=b.FireStationCode and a.CaseNo=b.CaseCode )
WHERE b.Update_DateTime <=20140628134416
```

It show error: `[Err] 1 - near "a": syntax error`

How delete table inner join with other table in Sqlite?

Comment: Sqlite does not accept this syntax unfortunately as being different from sql server.

Comment: PostgreSQL docs suggest `DELETE JOIN` is not part of the SQL standard BTW: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-delete.html "This syntax is not standard. A more standard way to do it is" with `IN`. However it also states "In some cases the join style is easier to write or faster to execute than the sub-select style." so it is a shame that SQLite doesn't support it, even if just for greater portability. Related for UPDATE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270259/update-with-join-in-sqlite

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Try to rewrite you query using subquery: In case your PK for `TR_ContactResultRecord` is `CaseNo`

```
DELETE FROM TR_ContactResultRecord
WHERE CaseNo IN (
  SELECT CaseNo FROM TR_ContactResultRecord a
  INNER JOIN TR_Case b
    ON (a.FireStationCode=b.FireStationCode and a.CaseNo=b.CaseCode )
  WHERE b.Update_DateTime <=20140628134416
);
```

Comment: Oh, so SQLite doesn't like `DELETE FROM table JOIN ...` ?

Comment: I get this error too, it seems sqlite doesn't support delete inner join

Comment: The select statement should probably be **a.CaseNo** instead of **CaseNo**. Otherwise great answer!

Comment: @Optavius: a.CaseNo or CaseNo is ok. because in b table has not column CaseNo.

Comment: Using this answer in conjunction with the ROWID automatically generated column mentioned in another answer was exactly what I needed to quickly check overlap between two tables using multiple criteria in the join, but a single column for the IN portion of the delete.

Answer (score 27):

SQLite has special ROWID column by default in each table. From official [documentation](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html):

> You can access the ROWID of an SQLite table using one of the special column names ROWID, _ROWID_, or OID. Except if you declare an ordinary table column to use one of those special names, then the use of that name will refer to the declared column not to the internal ROWID.

The code is following:

```
DELETE FROM TR_ContactResultRecord
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT a.ROWID FROM TR_ContactResultRecord a
  INNER JOIN TR_Case b
    ON (a.FireStationCode=b.FireStationCode and a.CaseNo=b.CaseCode )
  WHERE b.Update_DateTime <=20140628134416
);
```

Comment: Agree. Definitely the most performant, by a long shot.

Comment: This is the best SQLite specific solution

Comment: Why use `ROWID`?

Comment: @CervEd I *think* `ROWID` is used here because it doesn't require a unique key in the table

Comment: The answer could be improved. As it is, it's unclear how this answer is different from the accepted answer and in which situations one may want to use it.