# SQL Query Error: "sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1" when trying to match either of two columns of subquery

Tags: sql, cs50, querying

When I write the following query:

```
SELECT name
FROM people
WHERE phone_number IN 
(SELECT caller, receiver FROM phone_calls WHERE month = 7 AND day = 28 AND year = 2020 AND duration < 60);
```

I get the following error: **sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1**

Not sure where the issue is...
caller is TEXT with phone number.
receiver is TEXT with phone number.
My goal is to create a list where instead of showing me to caller and receiver's phone number, it'll show me their names instead.

Also, this is my attempt at CS50's fiftyville.

Answer (score 1):

What part of the error do you not understand?  The subquery for an `in` can only have one column.

In your case, I think you want either column to match.  So, use `exists` instead:

```
SELECT p.name
FROM people p
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM phone_calls pc
              WHERE pc.month = 7 AND pc.day = 28 AND pc.year = 2020 AND
                    pc.duration < 60 AND
                    p.phone_number IN (pc.caller, pc.receiver)
             );
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think I'm looking for something more like; 

`
SELECT 
    (SELECT name FROM people WHERE phone_number IN 
        (SELECT caller FROM phone_calls WHERE month = 7 AND day = 28 AND year = 2020 AND duration < 60 ORDER BY id)
    ) AS Caller,
    (SELECT name FROM people WHERE phone_number IN
        (SELECT receiver FROM phone_calls WHERE month = 7 AND day = 28 AND year = 2020 AND duration < 60 ORDER BY id)
        ) AS Receiver;
`
This is still not correct - but is a little closer to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use a JOIN instead of the subquery in this case? Something along:

```
SELECT name
FROM people
INNER JOIN phone_calls
  ON people.phone_number IN (
    phone_calls.caller,
    phone_calls.receiver
  )
  AND phone_calls.month = 7
  AND phone_calls.day = 28
  AND phone_calls.year = 2020
  AND phone_calls.duration < 60
```

This wouldn't work however with UPDATE/DELETE, as those don't support JOIN in SQLite unfortunately, in those cases I don't know how to avoid the correlated subquery as proposed by Gordon:

- [Update with Join in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270259/update-with-join-in-sqlite)
- [How delete table inner join with other table in Sqlite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511153/how-delete-table-inner-join-with-other-table-in-sqlite)